# Couting total views on all posts of an author, but the first

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm using a code to count the total number of views of the logged user's posts, but for some reason, it's not adding to the total the user's first post views. The funny part is that I've tested this in other users and it seems to behave like this only in my admin account.

This is the code:

```
<?php
    $author_posts = get_posts( array('author' => $current_user->ID) );

    $counter = 0; // needed to collect the total sum of views

    foreach ( $author_posts as $post ) {

        $views = absint( get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'post_views_count', true ) );
        $counter += $views;
    }
    echo "{$counter}";
?>
```

Any help is very much appreciated.

Comment: Please provide example input data, what you expect the output to be, and what the output actuall is.

Comment: How about instead of adding to the counter you add it to an array where `$counts[$post->ID] = {the count}` and do a var_dump on that to see what posts are count and  if there is a post not being counted. Then you can at least narrow it down to whether or not all the posts is being selected which is likely the case. You can also go look at all the posts in your database and double check the user id for all the posts you expect. Possible you are expecting a post that isn't under your id.

Comment: @dg99 I have like 3 posts:

First post: 10 views
Second post: 5 views
Third post: 4 views

The total view count should be 19, but it's not counting the first post I've published, so the total is only 9 views.

Comment: @JonathanKuhn It's a fresh setup with very few posts, so very easy to keep track on the posts... The counter is missing the first post I've published.

Comment: Does `$author_posts` have all the posts though? Look at a print_r of the array. If not, like I said, double check the database tables for the posts to make sure all the poster ids match `$current_user->ID`. If all the posts show up in `$author_posts`, what count is being returned for each of the posts from `get_post_meta`. Make sure it is what you expect. Double check the post count in the database as well.